# d3 bar chart obscured in firefox but not in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, d3.js

I have strange case with d3 bar chart.
I am able to see it fine with chrome, but in firefox it behaves as if some element is overlaying some part of it. But when I viewed the page in 3D in firefox it shows me the rectangles but they are just not visible on page.
I am including the generated HTML generated with d3, which in chrome and firefox behave differently.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bar_chart.js"></script><script  type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.v3.min.js"></script></head>
<body>
<div style="position:fixed;
    position:obsolute;/*for ie6*/
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1.0);
    height:206px;
    width: 100%;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;" class="plot" id="barchart">

<br><br>
<p class="bob"></p>
<svg class="bar"><g transform="translate(20,0)"><line x1="0" x2="1295" y1="149.5"  y2="149.5" style="stroke: #ffffff;"></line><line x1="0" x2="1295" y1="119.5" y2="119.5" style="stroke: #cccccc;"></line><line x1="0" x2="1295" y1="89.5" y2="89.5" style="stroke: #cccccc;"></line><line x1="0" x2="1295" y1="59.5" y2="59.5" style="stroke: #cccccc;"></line><line x1="0" x2="1295" y1="29.5" y2="29.5" style="stroke: #cccccc;"></line><line x1="0" x2="1295" y1="-0.5" y2="-0.5" style="stroke: #cccccc;"></line><rect x="-0.5" y="119.5" width="64" height="30" fill="steelblue"></rect><rect x="63.5" y="89.5" width="64" height="60" fill="steelblue"></rect><rect x="127.5" y="71.5" width="64" height="78" fill="steelblue"></rect><rect x="191.5" y="35.5" width="64" height="114" fill="steelblue"></rect>
<rect x="255.5" y="23.5" width="64" height="126" fill="steelblue"></rect><rect x="319.5" y="-0.5" width="64" height="150" fill="steelblue"></rect><rect x="383.5" y="17.5" width="64" height="132" fill="steelblue"></rect><rect x="447.5" y="41.5" width="64" height="108" fill="steelblue"></rect><rect x="511.5" y="59.5" width="64" height="90" fill="steelblue"></rect><rect x="575.5" y="71.5" width="64" height="78" fill="steelblue"></rect><rect x="639.5" y="83.5" width="64" height="66" fill="steelblue"></rect><rect x="703.5" y="77.5" width="64" height="72" fill="steelblue"></rect><rect x="767.5" y="59.5" width="64" height="90" fill="steelblue"></rect><rect x="831.5" y="29.5" width="64" height="120" fill="steelblue"></rect><rect x="895.5" y="41.5" width="64" height="108" fill="steelblue"></rect><rect x="959.5" y="47.5" width="64" height="102" fill="steelblue"></rect><rect x="1023.5" y="53.5" width="64" height="96" fill="steelblue"></rect><rect x="1087.5" y="41.5" width="64" height="108" fill="steelblue"></rect><rect x="1151.5" y="11.5" width="64" height="138" fill="steelblue"></rect><rect x="1215.5" y="-0.5" width="64" height="150" fill="steelblue"></rect><text class="rule" x="0" y="149.5" dx="6" text-anchor="middle" fill="white" font-size="14px">0</text><text class="rule" x="0" y="119.5" dx="6" text-anchor="middle" fill="white" font-size="14px">5</text><text class="rule" x="0" y="89.5" dx="6" text-anchor="middle" fill="white" font-size="14px">10</text><text class="rule" x="0" y="59.5" dx="6" text-anchor="middle" fill="white" font-size="14px">15</text><text class="rule" x="0" y="29.5" dx="6" text-anchor="middle" fill="white" font-size="14px">20</text><text class="rule" x="0" y="-0.5" dx="6" text-anchor="middle" fill="white" font-size="14px">25</text></g></svg></div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is already addressed in the following thread:
[SVG renders but gets cut off in Firefox only - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12830897/svg-renders-but-gets-cut-off-in-firefox-only-why)
Thank you.