# Using Radio Buttons to Show/Hide Content

Tags: jquery, html, d3.js, radio-button

I have data in the form of JSON, and I'm trying to visualize it using D3.js. I want to give the user the option of what graph they view the data in. I tried, without success, to do a smooth transition between the two, so I decided to just do it with radio buttons. Here is what I got:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($("input[name='chart']:checked").val() == 'pie') {
        // ... Graph 1
    } else if ($("input[name='chart']:checked").val() == 'bar') {
        // ... Graph 2
    }
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/k3WJN/2/)

This shows the graph that has its radio button checked off when it loads. However, when I click the buttons, they don't change. I did some research and found that I likely need to include the change() function. Here is what I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name=chart]:radio").change(function () {
        if ($("#chart1Pie").attr("checked")) {
            // ... Graph 1
        } else if ($("#chart1Bar").attr("checked")) {
            // ... Graph 2
        }
    });
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/k3WJN/1/)

There are a few things wrong with this. 1) The selected graph does not load when the page is loaded. 2) When a radio button is clicked, only the pie chart appears. 3) When the other radio button is clicked, the previous graph does not go away; it just puts the new one below it.

I've looked at several StackOverflow questions, and none of them solved the problem. Can someone help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 3 things to do to make it work.

**1:** Before entering into the first condition, do this :

```
$('#chart').empty();
```

**2:** instead of :

```
if ($("#chart1Pie").attr("checked"))
```

do :

```
 if ($("#chart1Pie").is(":checked"))
```

**3:** Right after declaring the `.change()` function, insert this :

```
$('input:radio:first').trigger('change');
```

it will trigger it and show a graph.

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/k3WJN/13/

Comment: A lot of problems happen when people use .attr when they should be using .prop.  In Karl-Andre's answer, if ($("#chart1Pie").prop("checked")) will return true and false.  Read the api for more info: http://api.jquery.com/prop/.

Comment: +1 crap firefox. Did not show there is already an answer. and i ended up posting another answer.

Comment: 1 more question. How would I transition smoothly between the two graphs? (e.g. using .slideToggle, .fadeToggle, etc). I tried adding two slideToggles in each if statement, but that looks horrible.

Comment: You slideUp first, then in the slideup callback you empty the chart and create the other one. at the end of the slideup callback, you slide down : http://jsfiddle.net/k3WJN/30/

Comment: This doesn't work. A title and the radio buttons are floated above the graph. This screws up the animation. Is there any way around this? Or should I just re-position these things somewhere else? http://jsfiddle.net/k3WJN/31/

Comment: This problem only occur in firefox. Unfortunatly, i can tell why. Googled a bit and found this thread, you may find something usefull : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872172/d3-bar-chart-obscured-in-firefox-but-not-in-chrome