# D3 JS Graphs not getting toggled on click of radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js, svg

I've been working with a D3 svg chart along with jquery to trigger some radio buttons that will show different graphs for which I used this answer:
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/17195138/4877962 
Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/k3WJN/13/ 
I am getting the data from different urls, in order to populate log count as per day and week from datetime. Below is the html template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar {
  fill: #00a4ff;
}

.bar:hover {
  fill: #ffb900;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.d3-tip {
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 12px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

/* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip */
.d3-tip:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  content: "\25BC";
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Style northward tooltips differently */
.d3-tip.n:after {
  margin: -1px 0 0 0;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

</style>
<body>


<form id="chart1" action="" class="radioButtons">
    <input type="radio" name="chart" id="chart1Daily" value="daily" checked>Daily Log Run
    <input type="radio" name="chart" id="chart1Weekly" value="weekly">Weekly Log Run
</form>
<div id="chart"></div>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("input[name=chart]:radio").change(function () {
    $('#chart').slideUp('slow', function(){
      $('#chart').empty()
      if ($("#chart1Daily").is(":checked")) {
        var margin = {top: 40, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
        width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        // var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse; // for dates like "2014-01-01"
        var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ").parse;  // for dates like "2014-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .rangeBands([0, width], 0.2);

        var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([height, 0]);

        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .orient("bottom");

        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y)
            .orient("left");

        var tip = d3.tip()
          .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
          .offset([-10, 0])
          .html(function(d) {
            return "<strong>Log Count:</strong> <span style='color:#fff'>" + d.count_items + "</span>";
          })


        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
          .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
          .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        svg.call(tip);

        d3.json("{% url "log_count_by_day" %}", function(error, data) {
          data.forEach(function(d) {
            formatDate = d3.time.format("%H h")
            d.hour = formatDate(parseDate(d.hour))
            d.count_items = +d.count_items;
          });

          x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.hour; }));

          // y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.count_items; }));
          y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.count_items; })]);

          svg.append("g")
              .attr("class", "x axis")
              .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
              .call(xAxis);

          svg.append("g")
              .attr("class", "y axis")
              .call(yAxis)
            .append("text")
              .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
              .attr("y", -38)
              .attr("dy", ".71em")
              .style("text-anchor", "end")
              .text("Log count");

          svg.selectAll(".bar")
                .data(data)
              .enter().append("rect")
                .attr("class", "bar")
                .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.hour); })
                .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
                .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.count_items); })
                .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.count_items); })
                .on('mouseover', tip.show)
                .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
        });
      }
      else if ($("#chart1Weekly").is(":checked")) {
        var margin = {top: 40, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
        width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        // var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse; // for dates like "2014-01-01"
        var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ").parse;  // for dates like "2014-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
          .rangeBands([0, width], 0.2);

        var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([height, 0]);

        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .orient("bottom");

        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y)
            .orient("left");

        var tip = d3.tip()
          .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
          .offset([-10, 0])
          .html(function(d) {
            return "<strong>Log Count:</strong> <span style='color:#fff'>" + d.count_items + "</span>";
          })


        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
          .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
          .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        svg.call(tip);

        d3.json("{% url "log_count_by_week" %}", function(error, data) {
          data.forEach(function(d) {
            formatDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y")
            d.day = formatDate(parseDate(d.day))
            d.count_items = +d.count_items;
          });

          x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.day; }));

          // y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.count_items; }));
          y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.count_items; })]);

          svg.append("g")
              .attr("class", "x axis")
              .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
              .call(xAxis);

          svg.append("g")
              .attr("class", "y axis")
              .call(yAxis)
            .append("text")
              .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
              .attr("y", -38)
              .attr("dy", ".71em")
              .style("text-anchor", "end")
              .text("Log count");

          svg.selectAll(".bar")
                .data(data)
              .enter().append("rect")
                .attr("class", "bar")
                .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.day); })
                .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
                .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.count_items); })
                .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.count_items); })
                .on('mouseover', tip.show)
                .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
        });
      }
    $('#chart').slideDown('slow');

    })
  });
  $('#chart').hide()
  $('input:radio:first').trigger('change');
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I run the code, I am getting the graphs one below the other and keeps adding instead of hiding the previous one and showing the new graph.
[image: Output Obtained]

I am successfully able to get the JSON object when I do the api call, here is the JSON object that I got:
For `log_count_by_day`:

```
[{"hour": "2017-09-30T03:00:00Z", "count_items": 2}]
```

and for `log_count_by_week`:

```
[{"day": "2017-09-28T00:00:00Z", "count_items": 2}, {"day": "2017-09-30T00:00:00Z", "count_items": 2}]
```

My objective is to achieve something like in the Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/k3WJN/13/ where in one graph hides before populating the next, Can someone help me out on whats wrong with the code? Also is there any other better way in which I can tweak this code for more improved performance, instead of writing almost the same code in the `if` and `else if` loops, as both the graphs are almost the same but with different data and x-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake was somewhat silly instead of appending the svg to the `body`, it should have been appended to the id `#chart` 
`var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")` 
 This finally solved the problem.
Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/PmAvHqvvgsV6UwvGJFPw?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are appending a new SVG eveytime the choice is changed.

`var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")`<-- this will create a new  SVG everytime.

One way would be that you remove the old svg before creating a new one:

`d3.select("body").select("svg").remove();`

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/yI6skLqzXenEyEdt1qfG?p=preview)

In the example you posted as [refrence](http://jsfiddle.net/k3WJN/13/) `$('#chart').empty()`  is doing the same trick.*(i.e. clearing the svg appended to chart)*