# SVG being cut off

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, text, svg

I found an answer on here that I dont understand.  Unfortunately i am unable to comment yet.

Here is the link to the answer, [SVG renders but gets cut off in Firefox only - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12830897/svg-renders-but-gets-cut-off-in-firefox-only-why)

The Accepted answer by Boris Zbarsky has a description on why it is not working.  I do not fully understand this answer and wondering a way to correct this issue so I can make it work on Firefox.

For my case, the SVG text element is there on all browsers,
In Internet explorer all 3 texts are visible,
In Firefox and chrome any of the SVG text elements are cut off if they are more than 1/4 to the right of the screen.  If I move them through the developer tab to the left of the imaginary cut off they show up.

There is no div or block along this strange area that could be hiding the SVG text.

This is a local implementation.

Any help on what is happening would be very helpful.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

I had similar problem. Try to add css property:

```
overflow: visible
```

Comment: I was getting my svg circle elements cut off just by a half-pixel on either left or top. This totally fixed it.

Comment: Thanks, I added `style="overflow: visible"` to the SVG elements that were clipping and it worked. I used Chrome console to figure out which elements I needed to add the property to.

Comment: ***This works, but is a bandaid solution.*** Before using, double-check the [answer by Mark Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54505427/1447509) (below) -- it may be the more correct solution in many cases.

Comment: @cssyphus No, the solution proposed by you is a "bandaid". `overflow: visible` is the correct one, if mobile browser makers aren't intelligent enough not to cut off the stuff that desktop browser engines don't.

Comment: I spent so much time playing around with viewboxes. It may have been because I was using `<symbol>` tags, however `overflow: visible` seemed to be the only thing that helped.

Comment: I've been wondering about this for years. Glad to finally know the solution!

Comment: This worked for me too. I applied this on the svgIcon itself, not on a wrapping container such as a div.

Comment: awesome! my svg cut off on mobile when user zoom out font size and it works for me

Answer (score 37):

I had the same problem, turns out there was a clip-path in one of the tags.

```
<g id="undraw_the_search_s0xf 1" clip-path="url(#clip0)">
```

If you remove that it should render the full SVG.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me a lot. Overflow was doing nothing for me.

Comment: If it wasn't for stack... Thanks for posting!

Comment: I was struggling with a problem with my SVGs and your answer nailed it! It happens that, when you export SVG files from Illustrator, it embeds in its code the clip-path tag, which tells to the browser to clip everything off the drawing box.

Answer (score 11):

The x coordinate on the text element was larger than the width css that was applied to the parent SVG element.

Such a simple problem that had me running in circles for hours.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to fix this (or a similar issue) by adjusting viewBox: 
`<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100"` 
I played with the 3rd and 4th parameters and bringing them down to ~60 fixed it for me.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox

Answer (score 5):

In our case it is due to we render many SVG icons in one page, and they have the same clipPath id, when rendered in the same page, they will use clipPath from another icon.

Find out more about clipPath here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. My `<svg>` block fully renders in IE9, but is slightly cut-off in Chrome.

Fix:

```
<svg width="100%"></svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as well, and `style="overflow: visible"` did not work for me. Try adjusting your `viewBox` values if other attributes don't work.

```
<svg width="12" height="12" **viewBox="0 0 11 15"** fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M5.11598 6L0.557983 10.558L1.44198 11.442L5.99998 6.884L10.558 11.442L11.442 10.558L6.88398 6L11.442 1.442L10.558 0.557999L5.99998 5.116L1.44198 0.557999L0.557983 1.442L5.11598 6Z" fill="#11142D"/>
</svg>
```

You can know more about viewBox attribute values [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox)

Comment: It is always helpful to provide an example in code.

Comment: Yes done! Added the bit of code of the viewBox for the SVG

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, It was for a logo and to solve the problem I just needed to add more space to the right edge of the artboard within illustrator. Firefox was clipping the right side of the artwork by a fraction.

Firefox expands the content & If you don't have enough space/width at the edges of the content within the artboard it will be clipped by the artboard bounds (edge of space where content renders).

Solution: The Artboard size created in illustrator needs to be bigger around the artwork bounds to provide more space around the content in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Firefox 93.0. Included a SVG image, that was nicely displayed in all browsers. Even in Firefox, but not when I added `width="100%"`. The problem was, that I inserted the SVG as `<img>` istead of an `<object>`.

That was my solution:

```
<object data="./vectorized-graphics-file.svg" type="image/svg+xml" width="100%">
<!---Fallback--->
Your browser can't display SVG graphics.
</object>
```

Comment: That seems like a misleading error message. Just because the browser isn't displaying the image in the way you want doesn't mean that it can't display the image.

Answer (score 0):

I tried some suggestions above such as adding `overflow: visible` and that didn't work. But I also removed `clip-path="url(#clip0)"` from  and it seemed to render the full SVG fine again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in one of then SVG icons, I used the `overflow-visible` class from tailwind css but it didn't worked for me. I would suggest you to try adjusting your view box for the following issue for getting it work  `viewBox=" 0 0 22 22"`

Answer (score 0):

I was in a hurry and copy-pasted the SVG code right out of XD. It left in the filters. I removed these (as well as clip_paths) and it now works. Remove extraneous nodes.

```
        <defs>
          <filter id="Banner_2" x="0" y="0" width="143" height="147.125" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <feOffset dy="3" input="SourceAlpha"/>
            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" result="blur"/>
            <feFlood flood-opacity="0.161"/>
            <feComposite operator="in" in2="blur"/>
            <feComposite in="SourceGraphic"/>
          </filter>
        </defs>
```